# static and dynamic evolution of services

Tags: c++, architecture

I am reading about challenges of concurrent and networked software in pattern oriented software architecure vol 2.

> Service access often involves invoking remote operations on resuable
>   components like OMG event service, etc. Supporting the static and
>   dynamic evolution of services and applications is antoher key
>   challenge in networked software system.
>
> Evoution can occur in following way
>
> Interfaces to and connectivity between component service roles can
>   change, often at run-time, and new service roles can be implemented
>   and installed into and installed into existing components.
>
> It is even more challenging to determine how to access services that
>   are configured into a system **'on-demand'** and whose implementations are
>   unknown when the system was designed origanally. Here design challenge
>   are two-fold.
>
> 1. First, an applicatoin must export new services, even though it may not know their detailed interfaces.
> 2. Second, an applicaiton must integrate these services into its own control flow and processing sequence transparently and robustly, even
>      at run-time.

I need your help in understanding above text by answering following questions.

1. What does author mean by "Interfaces to and connectivity between component service roles can change, often at run-time" ? Request to explain with easy to undestand example.
2. What does author mean by two points mentioned on-demand challenges which mentioned above. Request elobartion on above two points.

Thanks for your time and help.

Answer (score 0):

> 1.What does author mean by "Interfaces to and connectivity between component service roles can change, often at run-time" ?

I'm not sure exactly.  Interfaces change overtime because:

- New technology standards can be adopted - say moving from SOAP to REST, or form XML to JSON, but that would happen slowly overtime through deployment - where as for me "runtime" is a memory space in which things run, and I don't see interfaces changing themselves taht fast - otherwise how could anyone integrate with them?
- The API or interface contract itself changes to fulfill business need.

> 2.What does author mean by two points mentioned on-demand challenges which mentioned above.

Hmmm, good design patterns tend to survive time well (they never change, because they are never broken - like SOLID).  The book you are refering to was written in 2000 I think - a lot has changed since then, so whilst the pattern may survive maybe the way we'd now describe it has changed (i.e what he means by "export new services" is open to interpretation)...

> 1.First, an application must export new services, even though it may not know their detailed interfaces.

Separation Of Concerns (basic OO stuff), all parts of your app don't (shouldn't) inherently know what the other parts are doing internally; likewise, as long as someone (including an external system) is satisfying the interface then who cares how it does so internally.

> 2.Second, an application must integrate these services into its own control flow and processing sequence transparently and robustly, even
>   at run-time.

I take this to mean that the program should never break, it should always compile, and if the application is dynamically creating and executing code (say based on user input) then there needs to be checks in-place so that the dynamic code doesn't break the app either.